# How to search a value in string words with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a search text auther and in my database authers columns like:

```
string authers = name,name2,name3;
```

how to get name where it is:

```
(from pap in db.Papers
where pap.Authers.Split(',').ToList().Equals(auther)
select pap).ToList();
```

i using this query and it did not work ???

Comment: What does didn't work mean?

Comment: Do you mean `"author"` rather than `"auther"`?

Comment: Please be more precise about your expected input and output. The question is unclear as it is now, which already led to 3 amazing "try this" answers - so clearly the answerers are not really sure what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pap in db.Papers
where pap.Authers.Split(',').Contains(auther)
select pap
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
(from pap in db.Papers
 where authers.Split(',').ToList().Contains((pap.auther)
 select pap).ToList();
```

Comment: Please add context to this answer. Code only answers without comments may help OP with the code but won't help him understand the basic misunderstanding..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var authArray = authers.Split(',').ToList();
var data = db.Papers.Where(pap => authArray.Contains(pap)).ToList();
```